# Json.NET change value and keep comments

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a human edited JSON (a config file) and need to programmatically change a value, but keep the comments and, optionally, keep the formatting, too. Is it possible with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? I have the:

```
JToken jobject = JToken.Parse(json);
jobject["name"] = name;
json = jobject.ToString();
```

But it removes all the comments and reformats the JSON string.

Comment: I don't think it's doable, the layout information(e.g. padding, useless spaces) is lost in deserialization. I wonder why this file can be modified manually and programmatically.

Comment: @DannyChen Formatting is not so important. Do not need to fully deserialize, e.g. [JsonTextReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm) keeps comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping comments is possible but formatting is a different story and I'm not aware of a proper way of doing it using Json.Net, however `JsonTextReader` has `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` and it should be possible to use them to preserve formatting to a degree but it feels hacky and fragile, hence if it is not really important I suggest to use Json.Net internal formatting.

Here is a sample for updating properties and keeping comments but not formatting.

```
        private static string Update(string json, object update)
        {
            var updateObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update));

            var result = new StringWriter();
            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(result);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                if (reader.Value == null)
                {
                    writer.WriteToken(reader.TokenType);
                    continue;
                }

                var token= 
                   reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment ||
                   reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName || 
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Path)
                   ? null 
                   : updateObj.SelectToken(reader.Path);

                if (token == null)
                    writer.WriteToken(reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
                else
                    writer.WriteToken(reader.TokenType, token.ToObject(reader.ValueType));
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
   //broken
   'CPU': 'Intel',
   'PSU': '500W',
   'Drives': [
     'DVD read/writer'
     /*broken*/,
     '500 gigabyte hard drive',
     '200 gigabype hard drive'
   ]
}";

            var update=Update(json, new { CPU = "AMD", Drives = new[] { "120 gigabytes ssd" } });
        }
```